# Hide element if in the same date and only show it once using ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i want to create time like in this example

[image]

and here's what i have

[image]

here's the code

```
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="(message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy') === (time  | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'); then today else showDate">
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #today>
    <p class="dividerDate">Today</p>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #showDate>
    <p class="dividerDate">{{ message.time }}</p>
  </ng-template>
```

does anyone have an idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to compare current time and last time, if its the same then don't display it

```
  <ng-container
  *ngIf="(message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy') === (time  | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy'); then today else showDate">
</ng-container>
<ng-template #today>
  <p *ngIf="(message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy') !== (messages[i-1]?.time  | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy')" class="dividerDate">Today</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #showDate>
  <p *ngIf="(message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy') !== (messages[i-1]?.time  | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy')" class="dividerDate">{{ message.time | date: 'dd MMMM yyyy' }}</p>
</ng-template>
```